# How can you restore health in Sword & Sworcery?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

Playing through Sword and Sworcery on the iPad - I've reached the point where I'm battling the first trigon.

It defeated me - so I was down to 1 star health. How can I regain some health?

I've gone through my stash of mushrooms and can't leave the current screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Method 1 : during a fight hold up the shield for a while and you'll see a circle closing in on you - when it gets close in you gain an extra star.

Answer (score 4):

You can restore health between battles by sitting down (such as in Logfella's cabin) or by eating a mushroom.

Comment: That doesn't help in this specific case though. As the OP mentioned, it's not possible to leave the area to get more mushrooms after you've entered the fight with the trigon.

Answer (score -2):

Also you can regain health by doing nothing.

Comment: Making blind guesses doesn't help.