# What is the point of mushrooms?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

Swords & Sworcery sometimes features blinking mushrooms, of which you can carry up to three. when you use one you kind of get hallucinations and that's it.

In areas where the song of sworcery works then the areas you can click on do highlight while the mushroom effect is active - but then you can't actually do the song in the first place until the effect wears off.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The other point with mushrooms is to heal you: [How can you restore health in Sword & Sworcery?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19246/how-can-you-restore-health-in-sword-sworcery/19649#19649)

So, under a mushroom effect you're both being healed and getting things highlighted to solve sprites. After the effect you'll be able to solved it.